# Integrating three <buttons> inside one form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I need to enable 3 HTML buttons in my form:

[image]

The first one works properly, the second one is doing the same as first, the third one is almost working, but after a second does the same as first.

I assume my form is simply blocking all other buttons from functioning properly, but I don't know what needs to be changed.

The code:

```
<form method="post" target="hidden_target" action="panel.php?something">

<input type="hidden" name="what" value="editNews">

<div class="newstitle">Title: <input type="text" name="tytul[%id]" value="%tytul"></div>
<div class="newstext"><textarea name="tresc[%id]" class="htmlEditor">%tresc</textarea></div>
<div class="newslink">Article link:<input type="text" name="link[%id]" value="%link"></div>
<div class="table-end"></div>
<div class="newsprzyciski">

<button class="button minibutton">Save changes</button> 
<button onclick="panel.php?someaction" class="button minibutton red">Remove</button>
<button onclick="javascript:someaction" class="button minibutton orange">Images</button>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but you can not pass and URL to the onclick function.

Comment: So I need to use another form for button nr 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do but I can sense it. Maybe it's not what you want, let's see.

The first should submit the form, so add `type="submit"` to it:

```
<button type="submit" class="button minibutton">Save changes</button>
```

The second should redirect to another page, you want to pass an URL but you do it wrong. Use this instead:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location=panel.php?someaction" class="button minibutton red">Remove</button>
```

The third should just execute a javascript function:

```
<button type="button" onclick="someaction()" class="button minibutton orange">Images</button>
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: 1st and 3rd works well, the 2nd one which is: `<button type="button" onclick="location=panel.php?module=content&amp;fun=showNews&amp;modify=true&amp;w=delNews&amp;id=%idmd5&amp;idNews=%id&amp;od=%od" class="button minibutton red">Remove article</button>` does not work

Comment: The button has `type=submit` by default. You need to explicitly add `type="button" only if you don't want it.

Comment: Previously something like this worked properly (removed article): `<a href="panel.php?module=tresc&amp;fun=showNews&amp;modify=true&amp;w=delNews&amp;id=%idmd5&amp;idNews=%id&amp;od=%od"><img src="gfx/usun.png" alt="Remove article"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
<button type="submit" class="button minibutton">Save changes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='panel.php?someaction'" class="button minibutton red">Remove article</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:someaction" class="button minibutton orange">Images</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

For the second and third buttons, add the attribute `type="button"`, as in `<button type="button" onclick="panel.php?someaction" class="button minibutton red">Remove</button>`. By default, unless you set `type`, a button will submit a form.

Comment: Good, I will try ;)

Comment: It works, but partially. The first and third works well. The second does nothing.